# Can you find the iterator for a list element given a pointer to the element?

Tags: c++, list, iterator

The question is probably pretty self-explanatory, but If I have an `std::list<T>` object, is there any standard method to get the iterator for an element, given a `T*` value which points to the element?

If `T` is a user-defined type, it seems like dereferencing the pointer and using `find_if` would do the job, but this seems inefficient to me. If you're trying to find an element in a container by value, it makes sense that you'd need to iterate through the container until you find something. But if you have a pointer, it intuitively feels like there should be a method that's more direct. My basic understanding makes me think that there should be some 1-to-1 relationship between a list item's iterator and its pointer since lists are doubly-linked in the STL, but I really don't have much to back this up.

I'm not very familiar with with C++ iterators, so if anyone could explain why there is or isn't a way to do this, that would be helpful.

**edit:** Potatoswatter provided a good C++11 solution but I'd still be interested if any C++03-compatible solutions were available.

Comment: I don't understand the question - are you asking how to find an element in a list, given a pointer to the element to be found?

Comment: `std::list<T>` hold objects of type `T`. Given an `std::list<T>::iterator`, you can get a reference to the object, which you can use to get the address of the object. However, the pointer will have no knowledge of the place of the object it points to in the `std::list`.

Answer (score 4):

There's no standard algorithm to find the iterator in a range that satisfies a condition. `find` uses the value of the element, but that's simply not the same thing. `find_if` with a lambda that compares addresses would work.

It's easy to write a generic version:

```
template< typename iter, typename t >
iter iterator_from_ptr( iter first, iter last, t * ptr ) {
    while ( first != last ) {
        // For C++03 compatibility, use &* first instead of addressof.
        if ( std::addressof( * first ) == ptr ) return first;
        ++ first;
    }
    return last;
}
```

Usage: `iterator_from_ptr( my_list.begin(), my_list.end(), ptr )`.

As you mention, it is inefficient, O(N) to be specific. Going faster is against the rules of C++: you have a pointer to an object which is a member of the `std::list` node, and the `list::iterator` is effectively a pointer to a `std::list` node. But there's (usually) no way to go from pointer-to-member to pointer-to-whole-object. (Not to mention the iterator abstraction getting in the way.)

Comment: `std::addressof` is not in `C++03`. I think it's worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Potatoswatter. I didn't mention this in the original question, but the `std::list<T>` doesn't have many elements, but `T` is quite large, so doing value comparisons could get complicated and potentially slow. `O(N)` is still a bit of a bummer, but for my particular problem it's definitely good enough.

Comment: @Matt As noted in the answer itself, just use `&*first`. As long as `T` doesn't overload the unary `operator &` (*shudders*) you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

Does `std::find()` in `<algorithm>` work for you? It should work if the value type has `operator==` implemented.

```
#include <algorithm>
auto it = std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), *ptr);
```

Comment: I don't think he wants that. There might be more than one items in the list that are equal to `*ptr`. He doesn't want the first one that matches `*ptr`. He wants the iterator that points to the item whose address is `ptr`.

Comment: That only became clear with a later comment in a different answer :-(

Answer (score 0):

While I am not recommending the below, this function does what you ask for. It relies on knowledge of the list implementation, so it is really just a fun exercise and should not be relied on in production code :)

```
template <typename T>
typename list<T>::iterator iteratorFromPtr(T* a)
{
 auto offset = offsetof(_List_node<T>, _M_data);
 void* ptr = (void*)a;
 ptr -= offset;
 return _List_iterator<T>(static_cast<_List_node<T>*>(ptr));
}
```

EDIT: Tested with gcc-4.8.2.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to define/implement the iterator in your class. I usually use the pointer if I don't want to implement an iterator.

Comment: This is `std::list`. It is not the OP's class and it already has an iterator implemented. A pointer also doesn't work as an iterator for a doubly-linked list.